# Datatablesbs is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatables

I am getting the error that datatablesbs is not a constructor on this line of code:

```
let table = new datatablesbs('#myTable',{
```

but when the table is loaded the error appears.

I am using these packages:

```
 "datatables": "^1.10.18",
    "datatables.net": "^1.11.3",
    "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.13.3",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
```

I am using this package so I can filter the columns. It worked previously, I havent worked on this functionality but seems like it doesnt work anymore.

Comment: `let table = new DataTable('#myTable',` that is a wrong class name. it has to be `DataTable` re-read the docs again.

Comment: @AnujShrestha thanks for the reply, I have tried this solution and it says DataTable is undefined. Also, in `app.js` I have defined datatablesbs like this: ```window.datatablesbs = require('datatables.net-bs4');
require('datatables.net-bs4');```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] in the question.

Comment: This task is fixed

Comment: If the problem is resolved (is that what you mean by "this task is fixed"?), then you are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) - especially if you think your answer will be helpful to other people.